# Overflow property on before and after pseudo elements

Tags: css

I am applying overflow property on before and after pseudo-elements. I am not able to get this behavior after that being applied.

```
p { 
   border: 3px solid green;
   background-color: rgb(177, 215, 252);
}
 
p::after{
  content: "hello";
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Before applying `overflow:hidden` to `p::after` it appears like this:
[image]

After applying `overfow:hidden` to `p::after` it appears like this:
[image]

**My question is what is this behaviour ? How overflow is working with pseudo element here.**

One more thing i noticed is that it only happens when display is set to inline block. Below is the example.

1.

```
p::after {
content: "hello";
background: red;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

2.

```
 p::after {
     content: "hello";
     background: red;
     display: inline-block;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: overflow:hidden change the basline of the element

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with the `pseudo-element`, this is an issue with the `display: inline-block` property and its default property value for `vertical-align`, which is `baseline`.

You can fix this either by using `display: block` or adding `vertical-align: top` to the pseudo-element.

```css
p { 
   border: 3px solid green;
   background-color: rgb(177, 215, 252);
}
 
p::after{
  content: "hello";
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p + p:after {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello this is text</p>
<p>Hello this is text - v2</p>
```

Comment: Here is one more example
In this text animation is created using ::before and overflow:hidden property. When we remove overflow property there is some change. Can you please check out why it's like that ?
 https://jsfiddle.net/adisingh17/yoe4p2bn/19/